# How to change outer level index in multi index in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index

I've a dataframe with multi-level index with 9 million rows as follows. I wish to change the 0 level index which is non-unique in some cases to numerical order containing unique indices. Here's sample input:

```
ORDER             NO         DATE
4200000303        1          2015-02-19
                  2          2015-02-19
                  3          2015-02-19
1200000303        1          2016-07-19
                  2          2016-07-19
                  3          2016-07-19
                  4          2016-07-19
1500000303        1          2017-08-19
                  2          2017-08-19
                  3          2017-08-19
                  4          2017-08-19
x8594345 rows
```

The desired output should be:

```
ORDER             NO         DATE
0                 1          2015-02-19
                  2          2015-02-19
                  3          2015-02-19
1                 1          2016-07-19
                  2          2016-07-19
                  3          2016-07-19
                  4          2016-07-19
2                 1          2017-08-19
                  2          2017-08-19
                  3          2017-08-19
                  4          2017-08-19
x8594345 rows
```

I've tried the following code:

```
transactions.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [list(range(0,transactions.shape[0])), transactions.groupby(level=0).cumcount()],
    names=['ORDER', 'NO'])
```

But it's returning a flattened dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) by first level only:

```
transactions.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                              [pd.factorize(transactions.index.get_level_values(0))[0],
                               transactions.index.get_level_values(1)],
                              names=['ORDER', 'NO'])

print (transactions)
ORDER  NO
0      1     2015-02-19
       2     2015-02-19
       3     2015-02-19
1      1     2016-07-19
       2     2016-07-19
       3     2016-07-19
       4     2016-07-19
2      1     2017-08-19
       2     2017-08-19
       3     2017-08-19
       4     2017-08-19
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. perfect solution!

Comment: But there are some non unique indices. I believe the factorize method is replicating the non unique indices again. Is there a way to eliminate this problem?

Comment: @chanakya Do you think `a =  transactions.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()` and then `transactions.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                              [a. ne (a. shift()). cumsum() ,
                               transactions.index.get_level_values(1)],
                              names=['ORDER', 'NO'])`?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but I would go for this now:

```
(df.reset_index()
  .assign(ORDER=lambda x: x['ORDER'].factorize()[0])
  .set_index(['ORDER','NO'])
)
```